# Plot different errorbars on panda concat plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, errorbar

I've made a function trying to plot some bars of the mean of some values in a dataframe. Where I'm having trouble is to add the respective errors for each of the bar plots. I can not seem to understand how one should use the *yerr* parameter correctly.

```
def env_mean_concat(dataframe_name, title_name, max_score):
  x = dataframe_name[dataframe_name['What environment did you use during the experiment?'] == 'Environment 1'].mean().rename('Environment 1')
  y = dataframe_name[dataframe_name['What environment did you use during the experiment?'] == 'Environment 2'].mean().rename('Environment 2')

  plot = pd.concat([x, y], axis=1).plot(kind = "bar", yerr=1) #yerr=env_std_dev(dataframe_name).values.T) 

  plot.set_title("Mean of " + title_name)
  plot.set_xlabel("Questions")
  plot.set_ylabel("Score")
  plot.set_ylim(0, max_score)
```

I've also made a function which returns the standard deviation of the data

```
def env_std_dev(dataframe_name):
  std_1 = dataframe_name[dataframe_name['What environment did you use during the experiment?'] == 'Environment 1'].std()
  std_2 = dataframe_name[dataframe_name['What environment did you use during the experiment?'] == 'Environment 2'].std()
  return std_1, std_2
```

[image: plot]

In the picture you can see the plot, but with yerr=1 for demonstration purposes.

What can I do to get *std_1* to be the error bar on the blue bar, and *std_2* to be the error on the orange bar?

Comment: Do you have a sample of your data? What does the x-axis represent? I feel like you could organize your data more easily to get what you want (e.g. `groupby('environment').agg('mean', 'std').plot()`). You could also look into the seaborn library

Comment: The [argument `yerr`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) takes a value, a list, or an array, and this is what you should provide. In your case, this could be a list of two values, then matplotlib assumes that the first is for all blue bars, and the second for the rest. Or a list of two lists with each three values, so each bar has its own errorbar. But as cripcate said - your approach is rather unconventional. Maybe there are better ways to achieve the desired plot but you have to provide your data structure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Off course it was just me having trouble understanding the structure of *yerr*!

**Changed the deviation code**

```
def env_std_dev(dataframe_name):
  std_1 = dataframe_name[dataframe_name['What environment did you use during the experiment?'] == 'Environment 1'].std()
  std_2 = dataframe_name[dataframe_name['What environment did you use during the experiment?'] == 'Environment 2'].std()

  std = [std_1.to_numpy(), std_2.to_numpy()]
  
  return std
```

Which now when setting

```
yerr=env_std_dev(dataframe_name)
```

in *env_mean_concat* gives us my wanted plot:
[image]

Thanks to the guys pointing me in the right direction. I'll have a look at seaborn in the future for sure!